# What's the probability that triangle area will be smaller than 7.25

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

> Rectangle edges equals **a=2.9** and **b=6.3**. In adjacent rectangle edges  randomly selected two points and straight line drawn through them. What is the
>   probability that drawn triangle area is smaller than **c=7.25**.

I don't know how exactly the graph should look like.
Appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the random sides of the triangle X and Y. These are uniform random variables with uniform distributions on $[0,6.3]$ and $[0,2.9]$ resp. They are independent and their joint distribution is uniform on the rectangle $R=[0,6.3]*[0,2.9]$. Your condition is $XY/2\le 7.25$ That is $XY\le 14.5$. The probability you need is the ratio between the area under the hyperbola inside R and the area of R. This is an easy calculus exercise.